# How do I show that $h_n=\begin{cases}n!2^{\frac{n}{2}-1} , \text {if $n$ is even} \\ 0, \text{if $n$ is odd} \end{cases}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, generating-functions

> We have $n $ distinct cards. We want to split these cards into non-empty subsets so that each subset contains even number of elements. Then we want to order the cards in each subset. Finally we want to order these subsets into a line. Let $h_n$ be the number of ways to build this structure. $h_n$?
>
> Now
>   $$
> a_j= \begin{cases}
> j!, &\text{if $j>0$ is even}\\
>  0, &\text{otherwise}
> \end{cases},$$ and $b_k=k!, b_0=1$.
>
> So,  $$A(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}(2n)!\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}=\sum_{n\geq 1}x^{2n}=\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}$$
>   and
>   $$B(x)=\sum_{k\geq 0}(k)!\frac{x^{k}}{(k)!}=\sum_{k\geq 0}x^k=\frac{1}{1-x}$$
>
> Then $h_0=1$ and 
>   $$
> \begin{split}
> \sum_{n\geq 0}h_n\frac{x^n}{n!} &= H(x)\\
>      &= B(A(x))\\
>      &=\frac{1}{1-\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}}=\frac{1}{1-2x^2}-\frac{x^2}{1-2x^2}\\ 
>      &=\sum_{n\geq 0}2^nx^{2n}-\sum_{n\geq 0}2^nx^{2n+2}\\
>      &=1+\sum_{n\geq 1}2^nx^{2n}-\sum_{n\geq 1}2^{n-1}x^{2n}\\
>      &=1+\sum_{n\geq 1}(2^n-2^{n-1})x^{2n}\\
>      &=1+\sum_{n\geq 1}2^{n-1}x^{2n}\\
>      &=1+\sum_{n\geq 1}{2^{n-1}n!}\frac{x^{2n} }{n!}
> \end{split}
> $$

Now how do I show that $$h_n=\begin{cases}n!2^{n/2-1}, & \text{if $n$ is even} \\ 0, & \text{if $n$ is odd} \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note
$$
\sum h_n \frac{x^n}{n!}
 = 1 + \sum_{n \ge 1} 2^{n-1}x^{2n}
 = 1 + \sum_{n \ge 1} 2^{n-1} (2n)! \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}
$$
and using $k=2n$ to make sure $k$ is even, we get
$$
 \sum_{k \text{ even}} 2^{k/2-1} k! \frac{x^k}{k!}
$$
as desired.